# Vb.Net Web application with webform page add webapi 2.2

Tags: .net, vb.net, api, webforms

- I have web application project in Vb.Net

  - I want to add web api to my project
  - Visual studio 2019 with .Net 4.7.2

but when  I run the application it throws an error :

> Line 27:  Line 28:         ' Code that runs on application startup
>   Line 29:         GlobalConfiguration.Configuration(AddressOf 
>   AppStart.WebApiConfig.Register) Line 30:
>   ''GlobalConfiguration.Configuration(Register)

output :

> Microsoft (R) Visual Basic Compiler version 14.8.3761 for Visual Basic
>   2012 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> This compiler is provided as part of the Microsoft (R) .NET Framework,
>   but only supports language versions up to Visual Basic 2012, which is
>   no longer the latest version. For compilers that support newer
>   versions of the Visual Basic programming language, see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=533241
>
> C:project\webapp\global.asax(29) : error BC30545: Property access must
>   assign to the property or use its value.
>
> ```
>     GlobalConfiguration.Configuration(AddressOf AppStart.WebApiConfig.Register)
> ```

---

I've downloaded all the packages from nuget:

- Microsoft.asp.net.wabapi
- Microsoft.asp.net.wabapi.clinet
- Microsoft.asp.net.wabapi.Core
- Microsoft.asp.net.wabapi.selfHost

**global.asax**

```
Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

        ' Code that runs on application startup
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration(AddressOf AppStart.WebApiConfig.Register)

End Sub
```

**webapiconfig class**

```
Imports System.Web.Http

Namespace AppStart

    Public Class WebApiConfig

        Public Shared Sub Register(configuration As HttpConfiguration)

            '// Web API routes
            configuration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()

            configuration.
                          Routes.
                          MapHttpRoute(
                                      "API Default",
                                      "webapi/{controller}/{id}",
                                       New With {Key .id = RouteParameter.Optional}
                          )
        End Sub

    End Class

End Namespace
```

webconfig

```
<system.webServer>
      <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
      <handlers>

        <!--webapi-->
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
        <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
        <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
        <!-- end web api -->

</handlers>
<system.webServer>
```

*Thank you in advance for any help*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I did was to update the `web.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
```

by removing xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
```

It looks like this line led to this error:

```
Microsoft (R) Visual Basic Compiler version 14.8.3761 
for Visual Basic 2012 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. 
All rights reserved.
which is no longer the latest version. 
For compilers that support newer versions of the Visual Basic programming language, see
```